# How can I get rid of the "Info:" prefix on my sl4j/logback NetBeans console?

Tags: java, netbeans, logback, slf4j

This "should" be trivial. My NetBeans 8.2 Payara(GlassFish) Output log prepends EVERY line with "Info: ".. no matter the logging level. How do you get rid of this?

My logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{ss.SSS} %-5level %-28logger{5} %msg%n</Pattern>
            <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Sample output:

```
Info:   NeuroCraft was successfully deployed in 767 milliseconds.
Info:   06.251 INFO  c.o.n.w.WebsocketRouter      Connection opened: 3972aac1-e72a-45f2-8fa6-2b8d91141d75
Info:   08.379 INFO  c.o.n.m.NetworkThreadRunner  Run started.
Info:   08.381 INFO  c.o.n.c.NetworkController    Calibrated.
Info:   10.059 INFO  c.o.n.m.NetworkThreadRunner  Walk started.
Info:   10.524 INFO  c.o.n.c.NetworkController    Calibrated.
```

Why does every line start with "Info:   "????

Oh, and my pom.xml fragment:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't log to CONSOLE, log to a file instead.

When your code is writing a log entry, Logback will build the log message starting with `06.251 INFO ...`, then write that message to "console". The app server (GlassFish) is intercepting that output and logging it to the application log (file and/or real console) as an INFO-level log message.

You're basically sending out from one logging framework (Logback) into another logging framework (the one used by GlassFish).

Comment: Well. That makes perfect sense. Thanks! i guess it's worth leaving it as is just for the convenience of testing in NetBeans.